# CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTOR/CFSTR_FILECONTENTS 'Copying Files' Dialog missing

Tags: c++, windows, ole, windows-shell

I have a namespace extension that supports copy-paste using the `CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTOR/ CFSTR_FILECONTENTS` to copy virtual files to the clipboard. However, the 'Copying Files...' progress dialog does not show up.

Explorer appears to hang until the copy operation is complete.

Any suggestions as to how to get the progress dialog to work?

Thanks,
Mridul.

Answer (score 1):

Well... that was a straight forward fix... Ensure that for the FILEDESCRIPTOR object, `FILEDESCRIPTOR.dwFlags |= FD_PROGRESSUI;`

Mridul.