# Using COM to copy virtual files to Explorer from .net

Tags: c#, vb.net, winapi, com, c++-cli

I am trying to use IStream in VB.NET to copy virtual files to Windows Explorer using a wrapper class that chains calls to my own IO.Stream implementation.

I am using my own implementation of IDataObject to transfer data to Explorer using CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTOR and CFSTR_FILECONTENTS.

Everything seems to work fine (even with >1GB files), except the target Windows Explorer window stops responding until the operation completes.

The answer here - [CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTOR/CFSTR_FILECONTENTS 'Copying Files' Dialog missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534435/cfstr-filedescriptor-cfstr-filecontents-copying-files-dialog-missing) doesn't help.

My IDataObject Implementation is based on https://svn.cyberduck.io/tags/release-4-0/source/ch/cyberduck/core/VirtualFileDataObject.cs

The difference is, instead of loading the entire virtual file into memory before copying, I set CFSTR_FILECONTENTS to a pointer to an implemetation of IStream with this function:

```
Public Sub Read(pv() As Byte, cb As Integer, pcbRead As IntPtr) Implements IStream.Read
    Marshal.WriteInt64(pcbRead, 0, stream.Read(pv, 0, cb))
End Sub
```

Clarification: I am trying to transfer a file from my application to Windows Explorer and not the other way around.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Sorry for my English.

Comment: Your question is too broad, it's unclear what language you're using. No MCVE.

Comment: I am sorry, this is my first question.. I am using VB .NET although a reply for C# would work as well. Also the code is huge so I can't really get too deep into it. And what's "MCVE"?

Comment: MCVE = Minimum Complete Verifiable Example. You need to give us your code that's causing the problem, because at the moment your question is likely to be closed as Too Broad.

Comment: I'll try to edit my question in a few moments. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement the [`IDataObjectAsyncCapability`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706932(v=vs.85).aspx) interface to allow Explorer to extract the data asynchronously.

See [Dragging and Dropping Shell Objects Aynchronously](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776904(v=vs.85).aspx#async) for a description of how it works. The steps that the drop source needs to take to run asynchronously are:

> 1. Create a data object that exposes IAsyncOperation/IDataObjectAsyncCapability.
> 2. Call SetAsyncMode with fDoOpAsync set to VARIANT_TRUE to indicate that an asynchronous operation is supported.
> 3. After DoDragDrop returns, call InOperation:
>
>    - If InOperation fails or returns VARIANT_FALSE, a normal synchronous data transfer has taken
>        place and the data extraction process is finished. The source should
>        do any cleanup that is required, and proceed.
>    - If InOperation returns
>        VARIANT_TRUE, the data is being extracted asynchronously. Cleanup
>        operations should be handled by EndOperation.
> 4. Release the data object.
> 5. When the asynchronous data transfer is complete, the data object normally notifies the source through a private interface.

Comment: Thank you, for some reason I set IsAsynchronous to False, setting it to True was indeed the solution.